# How do you determine if two HashSets are equal (by value, not by reference)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, set, hashset

I am trying to determine if two `HashSet` objects in .NET 3.5 (C#) are equal sets, *i.e.* contain the same values. This seems like something one would obviously want to do but none of the provided functions seem to give you this information.

The way I can think to do this is by checking if the count of the two sets are equal *and* one set is a subset (not proper) of the other. I think the only way that can happen is if they are equal sets. Example code:

```
HashSet<int> set1 = new HashSet<int>();
set1.Add(1);
set1.Add(2);
set1.Add(3);

HashSet<int> set2 = new HashSet<int>();
set2.Add(1);
set2.Add(2);
set2.Add(3);

if(set1.Count == set2.Count && set1.IsSubsetOf(set2))
{
    // do something
}
```

Would this always work? Is there a better way? Why doesn't `HashSet` have a  `public bool IsEqualSetWith()` function?

Comment: It's called IEqualityComparer :)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with SetEquals.

Comment: Note that the order of addition has nothing to do with hashset equality.

Comment: For anyone wanting an interface for accessing `SetEquals`, there is `ISet<T>` in `System.Collections.Generic`

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Look at the method [SetEquals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412096(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
my_hashset.SetEquals(other);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, I don't know how I completely missed that in the method list on MSDN...

Comment: Happens to everyone at one time or another. I just can't believe I beat out both Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell on a .NET question.  I guess they *do* have to sleep sometime.

Comment: Easy to miss. With the prefix "Set", the method looks like it is a mutator if you're not paying close attention

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: I never thought that way in a set theory context but an interesting catch anyway.

Answer (score 5):

```
IEqualityComparer<HashSet<int>> comp = HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer();
Console.WriteLine("CreateSetComparer set1 == set2 : {0}", comp.Equals(set1, set2));
// or
bool areEqual = HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer().Equals(set1, set2);
```

Comment: This is useful when you for example need to create a Dictionary where HashSet is used as a key.